# Creating XAML grid rows programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to generate a grid of data programmatically.

```
private void WorkPackageSearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EWP[] workPackages = SqlDataLayer.getSearchedWorkPackages(WorkPackageSearchBox.Text); 
    //declare variables
    RowDefinition RowDef;
    StackPanel StackP;
    TextBlock TextB;
    TextBlock TextC;

    for (int i = 0; i < workPackages.Length; i++)
    {
        //Define new Row to add
        RowDef = new RowDefinition();
        RowDef.Height = new GridLength(30);

        //Add row definition to Grid
        WorkPackageResults.RowDefinitions.Add(RowDef);

        //Define the control that will be added to new row
        TextB = new TextBlock();
        TextB.Text = workPackages[i].EWPStatus;
        //TextB.Width = 75;

        TextC = new TextBlock();
        TextC.Text = workPackages[i].EWPCode;
        //TextC.Width = 175;

        //create stackpanel and define which row to add the stackpanel to
        StackP = new StackPanel();
        StackP.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);

        //add your control to the stackpanel
        StackP.Children.Add(TextB);
        StackP.Children.Add(TextC);
        //add the stackpanel to the grid
        WorkPackageResults.Children.Add(StackP);
    } 
}
```

The result is the data being added on top of each other:

[image]

How do I get each of the textblocks per iteration of the loop to be next to each other in a single row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Orientation of the StackPanel you're using to Horizontal

```
StackP = new StackPanel();
StackP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

the default Orientation of a StackPanel is Vertical, so it displays the items rows based.

[Msdn Link and Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.orientation(v=vs.110).aspx)